# SSL/TLS issue after upgrading runtime to net5.0

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, .net-5

I've the following code that prepares WCF client to connect external server using transport certificate (TLS 1.2):

```
var url = "https://clientsite/"

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url));

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var basicBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
basicBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

... 

var client = new wcfClient(basicBinding, endpoint);
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetCertificate();
```

Everything works fine until netcoreapp3.1 is used as runtime framework:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
RUN sed -i "s|TLSv1.2|TLSv1.0|g" /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Once changed to net5.0, I cannot force wcf client to connect.

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
RUN sed -i "s|TLSv1.2|TLSv1.0|g" /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

It ends up with the following message:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'clientsite'.

Is there any breaking change that corrupts this?

I don't want to disable verfication, I'd like to find a root cause.

Comment: Are both executions under the same machine or under two different ones?

Comment: They are executed as docker containers in the same k8s cluster. As you can see in the first place, the images are  different (due to .net core runtime).

Comment: Maybe it is not getting fine the openssl.cnf. Check the [Breaking change - Default TLS cipher suites for .NET on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux) and its "Recommended action"

Comment: What version of Net are you using?  You should be using Net 4.7.2 or later and targeting 5.0 Core.  Make sure you have latest 5.0.  There is a runtime version that you have to installed on deploy machines.  You also need to make sure the kernel on you target is compatible with 5.0.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography

Comment: @jdweng  ma using net5.0 and the latest docker image. So my machines doesn't matter since everything is hosted on docker ;)

Comment: I do not know what you mean by latest docker image.  With Net 4.7.2 and later the default TLS is done in the operating system.   Older version of Net TLS was  done in Net.  So docker has nothing to do with issue.  So the failure is either the operating system or the certificate is not loaded in both the client and server.  With TLS there is a certificate block where the server sends a list of certificate names to client. The client then looks up the certificate to get key.  In your case you are loading a certificate specific certificate.  The certificate you are using also has to be in server.